# Find the approximate standard error of the bootstrap distribution?

Tags: self-study, bootstrap, error

I am studying for an exam, not a homework question.

> According to a survey taken of 500 randomly selected US high school students, 62.9% plan to attend a four year university. A bootstrap distribution is created to find a 95% confidence interval for the true proportion of US high school students who plan to attend a four year university.
>
> What would be the approximate standard error of the bootstrap distribution?
> A. 0.0216
> B. 0.0223
> C. 0.0005
> D. 0.0135

The actual answer is A, but I'm not sure how to get there.

**What I have done:**

1. Find the standard deviation of the mean. At 95% confidence the standard deviation should be 1.96
2. SE = 1.96 / √n; the n = 62.9% of 500 which is 314.
3. I get 0.1106.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This should still have the self-study tag. Which bootstrap confidence interval method are you suppose to use.  Does the Professor specify?  If he doesn't you should ask him. For example some methods are  Efron's percentile method, bias adjusted bootstrap BC. Bias adjusted with acceleration constant BCa.  Peter Hall's percentile method and there are more.

Comment: Oh I didn't know there was a self study tag. I will try and find the method.

Comment: Thank you for adding the `[self-study]` tag. Please read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). This question now meets our standards & can remain open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\bar x = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ where $x_i$ is the indicator variable of whether the student attends 4-year university. Your data is $\bar x = 0.63$ and $n=500$.

Let $\mathbb P_n = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{x_i}$ be the empirical distribution of your observations. This simplifies to
$$
\mathbb P_n = \bar x \delta_1 + (1-\bar x) \delta_0
$$ 
which is a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\bar x$.

Let $x^*_i \sim \mathbb P_n$ be iid draws from this empirical distribution for $i=1,\dots,n$. $(x^*_1,\dots,x^*_n)$ is the bootstrap sample. Your bootstrap estimate of the parameter of interest is $\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x^*_i$ which has the mean $\bar x$ under the empirical distribution. The variance of this estimate (which will be your bootstrap estimate of the variance of the original estimator) is
$$
\mathbb P_n \Big(\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n x^*_i - \bar x\Big)^2 = \frac1n \mathbb P_n (x^*_1 -\bar x)^2 = \frac{\bar x(1-\bar x)}{n}
$$
where $\mathbb P_n$ above means the expectation under the empirical measure $\mathbb P_n$. (If this is too much notation just mentally replace it with $\mathbb E$.) The first equality is by iid nature of $\{x^*_i\}$. The second equality is by the simple formula for the variance of a Bernoulli variable.

Your bootstrap estimate of the standard error is then 
$$
\sqrt{\frac{\bar x(1-\bar x)}{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{0.629(1-.629)}{500} } =  0.0216
$$

EDIT: Also, as far as I understand, this is the exact standard error (or standard deviation if you will) of the bootstrap distribution of the sample mean. There is no need to approximate it, since it is obtainable in closed form in this case.

Comment: Holy cow, you are really good at this. So I use that formula because it is a one categorical?

Comment: @pewpew, I am not sure what formula you are talking about. I am hoping that my answer helps you understand what is going on, so that you don't need to rely on particular formulas. I am not sure at what level you were thought about bootstrap. Did what I wrote make sense to you?

Comment: Yes it makes sense now. Its funny now that you showed me how to do it I realized that the answer was right in front of me in my notes. But it really did help me that you showed me this. Thank you.

Comment: @pewpew, OK, I am glad that it helped.

Comment: Please be cautious when answering `[self-study]` questions. Our policy is to give hints to help the OP work through the question themselves, rather than to provide an answer for them. You can read our polices [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @gung, yes, I realized that (after the fact), but this one I believe deserved a more complete answer, since OP was quite off track and bootstrap is quite confusing. (This is a really simple example which helps in understanding what is going on, so there is no harm in answering IMO.)

Comment: I agree that there are mitigating factors in this case. I just wanted to make the general point for future reference.

Comment: This answer @passerby51 is a nice construction that reproduces one ofthe standard errors that the OP mentioned.  But he asked about four different estimates.  Also I thought the point of the exam problem is to construct a 95% bootstrap confidence interval for the parameter for the proportion. We haven't established which bootstrap confidence interval method he was suppose to use.to construct the confidence interval in which case he still has work to do.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, it seems that the question just asks for the standard error and is a multiple choice question (with one of the answers being the desired one). The mention of CI seems to be along the standard line of giving too much information in a question to throw students off balance. Although, it would be nice if you could write an answer and show what CI each of the approaches you mentioned produce in this example.

Comment: @passerby51 It is a long story and I don't have the time to go through.  You could look at books on the bootstrap such as Efron and Tibshirani or my bootstrap methods book. It seems that you are focused on the test here.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, thanks. I agree that it is a long story. That is why it would be nice to see a short summary of what different methods produce in this simple case. ( Say, for someone who has little time to read a book these days:) )